# Como pegar a posição de bottom uma div dinamicamente

Tags: jquery

Estou tentando pegar a posição do bottom de uma div dinamicamente via jQuery e não estou conseguindo.

O que preciso é pegar essa posição para fazer um limite de até onde o title da página possa ir dinamicamente, assim, posso usar o mesmo código em vários lugares.

Fiz um [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j26nvc95/17/) e o snippet abaixo para exemplificar melhor.

```js
var lastScrollTop = 0;
var max = 300; // bottom position dinamicamente
$(window).scroll(function(event){
  var st = $(this).scrollTop();
  if (st > lastScrollTop){
   if(st > max){
     var px = max;
    } else {
     var px = st;
    }
    $('.parallax').css('transform', 'translateY(' + px + 'px)');
  } else {
   if(st > max){
     var px = max;
    } else {
     var px = st;
    }
    $('.parallax').css('transform', 'translateY(' + px + 'px)');
  }
  lastScrollTop = st;
});
```

```css
div{
  background:url('https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/02/27/21/55/belly-3186730_960_720.jpg');
  height:300px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <h1 class="parallax">Teste</h1>
</div>

<br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
```

Comment: No exemplo que montou aqui na pergunta que parte em especifico não está a funcionar ? O que ficaria diferente para estar a funcionar como pretende ?

Comment: O exemplo está funcionando com um valor fixo de 300px. Quero que esse valor seja dinamico conforme a posição do elemento com a classe "parallax" para que eu possa utiliza-lo em outros lugares também. Para produzir esse efeito: https://willianjusten.com.br/novo-curso-aprenda-criar-sites-animados-greensock/